# how can i make a object shoot another object that has gravity in Godot GDscript?

Tags: godot, gdscript

im trying to make an NES-style godot 4 game where your goal is to shoot apples into moving baskets, i've already got player movement down, and i can *probably* get baskets working very easily using some sort of tweening,

all im looking for is a gdscript, keyboard key activated, shooting mechanic, that gives gravity to the thing being shot, like i just mentioned, im **very** new to godot, so a script i can paste and make slight changes to would be nice.

i tried my best to look online for this sort-of thing and came empty handed, any help would be much appretiated!

-Actionscripter

Answer (score 0):

While I'll be sharing code, I believe it is more useful to you to see the process of how to tackle such problems.

In general, it is also useful to start by breaking your problem into smaller ones. In this case:

- You need an object that can detect (or be detected in) collisions.
- You need an object that is affected by gravity.
- You need to be able to spawn it.
- You need to be able to give it an starting velocity and position.
- You need to spawn it when a certain input is received.

Ideally you could continue breaking things down until you can solve each problem with a single line of code.

*Chances are that you can find information online of how to solve these smaller problems.*

Also, in the process you might discover that there are multiple possible ways to solve these problems, and you have to pick.

I'll give you a reasonable approach, but be aware that there are alternatives, and sometimes the approach I pick here is not going to be ideal.

*You will also see it is not just code, there some other setup to do.*

*By the way, since you say NES I'm going to assume you are working in 2D. If you are working on 3D the situation would be similar, but I'm not providing code for 3D on the answer.*

---

**You need an object that can detect (or be detected in) collisions.**

This restricts your search to an static body, rigid body, character body, or area.

---

**You need an object that is affected by gravity.**

This leaves static body out of the question.

So you can:

- Use a rigid body, which will do this by default.
- Use a character body, and implement gravity on it.
- Use an area, and implement gravity on it.

How do you decide? By how it reacts to collisions.

- It only has to detect the collision: Use area.
- It has to stop on the collision, or have some other scripted motion: Use a character body.
- It has to bounce and be pushed around by other objects: Use rigid body.

Since we are talking of a projectile, I'm going to assume you only need to detect the collision. So area it is.

---

To detect collision on the area, you can use the `body_entered` signal. You can connect it to the same area in the inspector. It will create a method where you can write what happens when the collision is detected.

---

Let us implement gravity on an area.

We, of course want to extend `Area2D` (again, assuming you are working in 2D):

```
extends Area2D
```

And since we care about collisions, so let us work in `_physics_process`:

```
extends Area2D

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
   pass
```

We need to know the gravity. We can read it like this (or you can hard-code it, or whatever):

```
extends Area2D

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    var g := PhysicsServer2D.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity
```

We need to keep tract of the velocity:

```
extends Area2D

var velocity := Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    var g := PhysicsServer2D.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity
    velocity += g * delta
```

And move according to it:

```
extends Area2D

var velocity := Vector2.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    var g := PhysicsServer2D.body_get_direct_state(get_rid()).total_gravity
    velocity += g * delta
    global_position += velocity * delta
```

---

**You need to be able to spawn it.**

Since in practice it will not be just an `Area2D` (you need to add a collider as a child), and you also probably want to give it a graphical representation (e.g. a `Sprite2D`), the thing we will be spawning is an scene.

So create an scene with the `Area2D`, the above script attached, and the rest of `Node`s it needs.

The process is to:

- Load the scene.

  We can load it like this (which loads it on demand):

  ```
  var scene := load("res://path/to/the/scene")
  ```

  Or `preload` it like this (which loads it preemptively):

  ```
  var scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")
  ```

  Which could also be a `const`:

  ```
  const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")
  ```
- Instantiate it.

  We can instance it like this:

  ```
  var instance := scene.instantiate()
  ```
- Add it to the game world (scene tree).

  We can add it to the game world, for example as a child of the object that spawned it:

  ```
  var instance := scene.instantiate()
  add_child(instance)
  ```

  A common issue being that children move with the parent... One solution is to set the instance as top level:

  ```
  var instance := scene.instantiate()
  instance.top_level = true
  add_child(instance)
  ```

  Alternatively, you might want to add it as child of a different object, but I will not concern myself with that in this answer. Feel free to look into it if using `top_level` is an issue.

---

**You need to be able to give it an starting velocity and position.**

Since we already have a `velocity` property in the area, it is a matter of setting in the instance before we use it:

```
var instance := scene.instantiate()
instance.top_level = true
instance.velocity = initial_velocity
add_child(instance)
```

For the position, be aware that `position` is relative to the parent, and `global_position` is not... But:

- Once you add the instance to the scene, it will detect collisions, so you want it to be the correct position to begin with.
- Before the instance is in the scene, it does not have a parent.

I'd wish we could simply set the `global_position` before adding to the scene, but instead we need to set the `position` that it will have once it has a parent, for example:

```
var instance := scene.instantiate()
instance.top_level = true
instance.velocity = initial_velocity
instance.position = to_local(initial_global_position)
add_child(instance)
```

**Note**: You need to call `to_local` on the future parent of the instance, which is relevant if it is a different `Node`.

By the way, in practice you probably want the position to some offset from the parent, probably considering rotation, to match a barrel/cannon position. In which case you probably just set the `position`:

```
var instance := scene.instantiate()
instance.top_level = true
instance.velocity = initial_velocity
instance.position = initial_position
add_child(instance)
```

---

**You need to spawn it when a certain input is received.**

There are a few ways to get input. I recommend to start by using the `Input` singleton in `_physics_process` and only move to something else (such as `_input`) if that is not good enough for what you are doing.

Thus, let us do it in `_physics_process` with `Input`:

```
const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")

func physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        var instance := scene.instantiate()
        instance.top_level = true
        instance.velocity = initial_velocity
        instance.position = initial_position
        add_child(instance)
```

Ah, but you need to get `initial_velocity` and `initial_position` somehow.

Let us tart with the position.

And you can add a `Marker2D` as a child, so you can set the initial position visually in the edit. Assuming the `Marker2D` is called `"SpawnMarker"`, we can do this:

```
const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")

func physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        var instance := scene.instantiate()
        instance.top_level = true
        # instance.velocity = initial_velocity
        instance.position = $SpawnMarker.position
        add_child(instance)
```

If it is not a direct child, I suggest to use "Access as Unique Name" option, so you can use the `%` syntax, but then the position won't match, so use `global_position` like this:

```
const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")

func physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        var instance := scene.instantiate()
        instance.top_level = true
        # instance.velocity = initial_velocity
        instance.position = to_local(%SpawnMarker.global_position)
        add_child(instance)
```

About the velocity, you could export it, so you can set it form the inspector:

```
const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")

@export var initial_projectile_velocity := Vector2.ZERO

func physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        var instance := scene.instantiate()
        instance.top_level = true
        instance.velocity = initial_projectile_velocity
        # instance.position = initial_position
        add_child(instance)
```

But chances are you want to rotate it. You could use the `rotated` method of the `Vector2`:

```
const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")

@export var initial_projectile_velocity := Vector2.ZERO

func physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        var instance := scene.instantiate()
        instance.top_level = true
        instance.velocity = initial_projectile_velocity.rotated(global_rotation)
        # instance.position = initial_position
        add_child(instance)
```

Better yet, let us use a speed and use the `Marker2D` for direction:

```
const scene := preload("res://path/to/the/scene")

@export var initial_projectile_speed := 0.0

func physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("shoot"):
        var instance := scene.instantiate()
        instance.top_level = true
        instance.velocity = Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(%SpawnMarker.global_rotation) * initial_projectile_speed
        instance.position = to_local(%SpawnMarker.global_position)
        add_child(instance)
```

So you would not just use the `Marker2D` to specify the position form where the projectiles spawn, but also you would rotate it to give them direction.

---

Ah, but you said "shoot another object". You might want the direction to be towards that other object. Sure, if you can get a reference to it, you can get the direction to it:

```
var direction := global_position.direction_to(other_object_reference.global_position)
instance.velocity = direction * initial_projectile_speed
```

And it is going to miss because of gravity. Aiming considering gravity is a whole other thing, even more if it is aiming a moving object. That would be too much to cover here. *And also I need my time.* Thus, if you need that, please post a new question.